# The simulation model time slows down in virtual mode

Tags: anylogic

I am currently building a model on a manufacture process line and the simulation was running fine without errors. Suddenly  when I entered in virtual mode to run quickly the simulation, the model started to slow down although the step is high. I am trying to identify where the issue is but nothing is working. At a certain time , the simulation just stops while the step is still running.

[image: Model time]

This is a picture of the pallete, maybe the experiment is causing this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created an infinite loop, this can be triggered by various things in your model.

Likely, you have a ' while' loop not finishing, could also be a condition-based transition.

You need to find this yourself, though. 3 options:

1. (easy): Check the model logic yourself and find the problem
2. (easy): nudge yourself to where it stops with `traceln` commands (see where they stop showing, getting you closer to the culprit)
3. (harder): Use a profiler (google "AnyLogic profiling" or similar if you are not familiar)

Answer (score 1):

Benjamin is correct, you have created an infinite loop. Click on the "Events" tab in the developer panel and see which events are scheduled to occur at about the time that your model slows down to 0 days/sec. You can also pay attention to the "Step: " counter at the bottom of the developer panel and see where the step count spikes - e.g., if your model has roughly 10k steps per day, and suddenly starts climbing to 400k steps around 25.99 days, you can pay attention to which things are happening in your logic at that time and narrow down where the infinite loop is created. traceln will also help immensely